# Rust library for network-related functions

Tags: network, library, rust

I'm looking for Rust libraries that can help me manage and redirect network traffic within a LAN environment.

What I want is to handle the redirection of intercepted HTTP traffic

```
use hyper::{Client, Request, Uri};
use hyper::rt::{self, Future};
use hyper::service::service_fn_ok;
```

Is this okay or do I need to use another?

Comment: This is heavily opinion based, but if you provide clarification around a specific security use case(s) then you're likely to get some concise answers here.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a security matter. This looks like a pure programming question. But even as a programming question, you will need to explain what your requirements are. Else people will point you to the standard libraries

Comment: And how is this a security matter? This still looks like a plain programming question.